# Software to draw Codeflow

Tags: software-development, code-analysis, workflow, flowchart, dataflow

i am a newbie in coding. Now i am reading a big project source code and there are many thing need to be remembered. So i need to use a software to draw code flow and relationship betwwen functions in project. Could you recommend me a free software to draw flow of code and relation ship between functions ? Thank you so much

Comment: Take a look at our existing questions about [flowchart](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=flowchart)

Comment: Do you want to use UML?

Comment: It is a great idea to designs first, then code. However, if you put specially formatted comments in your code, tools such as [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can use them to generate up to date diagrams from your code. You can see some examples [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/results.html(